# Octave does not plot correct face color of marker

Tags: gnuplot, octave

What's wrong with my code?

`octave:26> plot([1;2;3;4],[1;8;27;64], 'marker', 'o', 'linestyle', 'none', 'marker', 'o', 'markeredgecolor', 'red', 'markerfacecolor', 'black', 'markersize', 20);`

It creates blue empty circles (with white background within the circles).

Version Info: GNU Octave, version 3.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a version issue.  Here is what I get with the latest version (3.6.1):
[image]

Are your colors inverted somehow?  White and black are opposites, and red and blue are sort-of opposites.  You may try different colors and see if they are systematically wrong.  Does it work if you delete the edgecolor or facecolor specifications?

Comment: thank you for the verification! almost certainly a version issue -- i'll doublecheck and accept your answer. i tried various permutations of deleting edgecolor / facecolor etc. and different colors: red, yellow, blue. nothing worked, so it is almost surely a version issue.

Comment: I confirmed this.  I had the same version (3.2.4, MinGW) and experienced the same problem.  I upgraded to 3.6.4 (Visual Studio) and now I get filled circles.